# For loop question, Why do I end up with an extra row R STUDIO

Tags: r

I ran a for loop to look for letters in my txt files and I calculated the probability of each letter I want and combined them into a new dataframe, but some how it create an extra row of 0s, I don't get where it came from

Please help!

Also If I want to add a new column for my file name, what is the best way to do it?

Here's what i have so far :

```
virus = data.frame()
for (i in virus_data){
b = read.table(i, header = FALSE)
str_split(b,"")
old_data = data.frame(A = str_count(b,"A")/str_length(b),
B = str_count(b,"B")/str_length(b),
D = str_count(b,"D")/str_length(b),
C = str_count(b,"C")/str_length(b))
virus = rbind(virus,old_data)}
```

it turns out like this

[image: It turns out like this]

Comment: what is the output from running `dput(virus_data)`?

Comment: Without any data or any information about the data, all we can do is guess. Are the results what you expect except for the blank first row? You can always get rid of it with `virus <- virus[-1, ]`.

Comment: @Jon Spring  the out put my directory of my 2 txt file

Comment: The data or the txt file contains over 20K letters in it without space

Comment: Nvm i figured it out thank you Jon! I created a new txt file to test and I forgot to delete it

Comment: FYI, iteratively adding rows to a frame using `rbind(old, newrow)` works in practice but scales *horribly*, see "Growing Objects" in [The R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). for each row added, it makes a complete copy of all rows in `old`, which works but starts to slow down a lot. It is far better to produce a list of these new rows and then `rbind` them at one time; e.g., `out <- list(); for (...) { out <- c(out, list(newrow)); }; alldat <- do.call(rbind, out);`.